# List folders with size and number of files

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, filesystem

I'm trying to clean up my files and I'm struggling with some command line stuff.

With the command

```
du -sh *
```

I can get a nice list of all folders where I use the command. How can I also get the number of files of each folder? i try to explain better:

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
macrofolder
|
+--folderA
|------file1
|------file2
+--folderB
|--file1
+--folderC
|------file1
```

How can I get something like this?

```
2MB     .          1 file
30MB    folderA    2 files
0MB     folderB    0 files
4MB     folderC    1 file
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from command line tools, something like this

`find . -type d -exec stat -f '%z     %N     %l' {} +`

Where `%z` is the size of the file in bytes but not the size of the blocks allocated to the files in the directory. `%N` the name of the file and `%l` the link count to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: despite put here, this is at the moment more a comment - but within these the script flow/line breaks are IMHOcompletely confusing. So I put it here (because I do not know better).

To get e.g. the number of files as well as the total size in a directory you can use:

```
    NUMBER=$(find . -type f -name '*' -exec du -ch {} +)
    N=$(echo "$NUMBER" | head -n 1 | wc -l)
    SIZE=$(echo "$NUMBER" | tail -n 1)
    echo "Number of files: $N"
    echo $SIZE
```

this will list the number of files as well as the total size for the selected folder.

Editing the *-name* pattern for *find* you can get this information for specific file types like e.g **.PNGs* etc..

Comment: it doesn't work :( gives me an error

head: illegal line count -- -1
Number of files:        0

Comment: Aaah, sorry - it has to be *head -n 1* somehow “-1” slipped in, corrected.

Answer (score -1):

Open a Finder Window, then select View>Show View Options, then tick the checkbox for "Calculate All Sizes", then click use as defaults.